# php response code

Tags: php, android, mysql

Здравствуйте. Пишу тестовую модель авторизации пользователя для очень простого клиент-сервер приложения на Android. Реализация такая : пользователь вводит на устройстве логин и пароль -> они отправляются на сервер, где логин и пароль ищутся с помощью mysql select'a. Если **mysql_num_rows() = 0** (пользователя с таким логином и паролем не существует), я вызываю метод **http_response_code(401)** 
Данный response code получает приложение с помощью метода **connection.getResponseCode()**

Так вот, вопрос : каждый раз, независимо от того, верный логин&пароль или нет, connection.getResponseCode() возвращает 200.

В чем может быть проблема или что я делаю не так? 
Вот код (заранее извиняюсь за его ужасность)

```
<?php

$mysql_host = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "db";
$mysql_password = "db";
$mysql_database = "db";

mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
mysql_select_db($mysql_database);
mysql_set_charset('utf8');

if (isset($_GET["action"])) {
    $action = $_GET['action'];
}

if (isset($_GET["username"])) {
    $username = $_GET['username'];
}

if (isset($_GET["password"])) {
    $password = $_GET['password'];
}

if ($action == authentication) {
    $query = "SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($rows = 0) {
        http_response_code(401);
        exit;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: **mysql_* !!!** Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможно вы просто опечатались. 
Проблема в условии

```
if ($rows = 0)
```

Вы, в данном случае, используете оператор присвоения. А вам нужен оператор сравнения == или ===

```
if ($rows == 0)
```

Про операторы сравнения подробно: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php

Для понимания: результатом выполнения оператора присваивания является само присвоенное значение. То есть, написав "if($rows = 0)" вы добились результата "if(0)", а внутрь такого условия выполнение никогда не попадет.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!